# How to align things in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

today I was working on a project and was struggling to align some things in TikZ. I'm very new to LaTeX and TikZ so if someone could take a look and help that would be great.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\vspace{5cm}
  \shade[ball color = gray!40, opacity = 0.4] (0,0) circle (1cm);
  \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
  \draw (-1,0) arc (180:360:1 and 0.3);
  \draw[dashed] (1,0) arc (0:180:1 and 0.3);
  \fill[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1pt);
  \draw[dashed] (0,0 ) -- node[above]{$1$} (1,0);
  \hspace*{3\linewidth}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \shade[ball color = gray!40, opacity = 0.4] (0,0) circle (2cm);
  \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
  \draw (-2,0) arc (180:360:2 and 0.6);
  \draw[dashed] (2,0) arc (0:180:2 and 0.6);
  \fill[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1pt);
  \draw[dashed] (0,0 ) -- node[above]{$2$} (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

I don't know how to make the spheres vertically aligned and put a horizontal distance in between them. Please help if you can!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!!

A possibility is to draw both spheres in the same `tikzpicture` environment. Then you can create a `scope` and shift the origin of coordinates for one of them.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % left sphere
  \shade[ball color = gray!40, opacity = 0.4] (0,0) circle (1cm);
  \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
  \draw (-1,0) arc (180:360:1 and 0.3);
  \draw[dashed] (1,0) arc (0:180:1 and 0.3);
  \fill[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1pt);
  \draw[dashed] (0,0 ) -- node[above]{$1$} (1,0);
  % right sphere, shifting the origin to the point (4,0)
  \begin{scope}[shift={(4,0)}]
    \shade[ball color = gray!40, opacity = 0.4] (0,0) circle (2cm);
    \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
    \draw (-2,0) arc (180:360:2 and 0.6);
    \draw[dashed] (2,0) arc (0:180:2 and 0.6);
    \fill[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1pt);
    \draw[dashed] (0,0 ) -- node[above]{$2$} (2,0);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Add the option `baseline={(0,0)}` to your `tikzpicture`s. The curly braces are necessary, because `(0,0)` contains a comma, which otherwise would be mistaken as separator between options.
The `baseline` option specifies the point to be used for horizontal alignment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)}]
  \shade[ball color = gray!40, opacity = 0.4] (0,0) circle (1cm);
  \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
  \draw (-1,0) arc (180:360:1 and 0.3);
  \draw[dashed] (1,0) arc (0:180:1 and 0.3);
  \fill[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1pt);
  \draw[dashed] (0,0 ) -- node[above]{$1$} (1,0);
  \hspace*{3\linewidth}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)}]
  \shade[ball color = gray!40, opacity = 0.4] (0,0) circle (2cm);
  \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
  \draw (-2,0) arc (180:360:2 and 0.6);
  \draw[dashed] (2,0) arc (0:180:2 and 0.6);
  \fill[fill=black] (0,0) circle (1pt);
  \draw[dashed] (0,0 ) -- node[above]{$2$} (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```